# Protractor + ionicPopup

Tags: protractor, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

Has anyone succeeded in using Protractor to detect an ionicPopup alert?
I've tried all the workarounds suggested [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1486) but no luck.
I need Protractor to detect the alert and check the text in the alert.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example using a public site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the class I wrote to test that the popup exists and to ensure the text is correct in the header and body:

```
var TestUtilities = function(){
    this.popup = element(by.css('.popup-container.popup-showing.active'));

    //Tests to see if $ionicPopup.alert exists
    this.popupShouldExist = function() {
        expect(this.popup.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
    };

    //Tests to see if $ionicPopup.alert contains the text provided in the argument exists in the header
    this.popupContainsHeaderText = function (text) {
        this.popupShouldExist();
        expect(this.popup.element(by.css('.popup-head')).getText()).toMatch(text);
    };

    //Tests to see if $ionicPopup.alert contains the text provided in the argument exists in the body
    this.popupContainsText = function (text) {
        this.popupShouldExist();
        expect(this.popup.element(by.css('.popup-body')).getText()).toMatch(text);
    };
};

module.exports=TestUtilities;
```

Also check out this site for more on testing Ionic in protractor it talks about how to check to see if the popup exists: http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-write-automated-tests-for-your-ionic-app-part-3/

Comment: Perfect answer!! This completely answers my question, including how to check for the text in both header and body, all wrapped in a nice, generic utility class. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I've tested Ionic popups successfully by setting the popup variable as follows:

```
var popup = element(by.css('.popup-container.popup-showing.active'));
```

And in the test:

```
expect(popup.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This worked. See also http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-write-automated-tests-for-your-ionic-app-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

Ionic Popups are just made of DOM elements, so you should be able to use normal locators to find/test them.  Because they're not made of alerts, the workarounds in the issue you linked to are probably not useful.

Answer (score 0):

I got it - I saw a lot of issues out there trying to do it in very complex ways, but in the end I tried this and it turns out to be this simple.

Inspect your element and find its ng-repeat value, then

`var button = element(by.repeater('button in buttons')).getText()`

You also need to have the browser sit out somehow for a couple seconds so it doesn't resolve to the tests while the ionic popup isn't actually there.

For that, `browser.sleep(3000);`

That's it! However, getting the other button in there is proving to be a little problem. `var button = element(by.repeater('button in buttons')).get(0)` or `.get(1)` return undefined is not a function.

Please accept the answer if you like it! If I figure out how to get the other button, I'll post it here.

Comment: This did not work for me. I got: NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.repeater("button in buttons")

Comment: You have to inspect the element and see what they use for repeater, i.e. banana in bananas ?